# R Making a calculation generic

Tags: r, function

Im having some trouble building a function (or using some apply smartly) in R. I have a dataset like this:

```
df<- data.frame( id <-sample(1:10,100, replace = T),
price <-runif(20)*100,
q = sample(1:100,100, replace = T))
colnames(df)<-c("id","price","quantity")
```

Now I need to calculate the average price for each individual ID. So I can do it by each different id like this:

```
sum(((df$p[df$id == "1" ])*(df$q[df$id == "1" ])/(sum(df$q[df$id == "1" ]))))
```

But how do I make it go through all possible values of df$id and print it as a matrix/df, which also contains the ID alongside the sum? I have around 6000 different ID's and around 180000 obs. so it would be nice if it was also possible to do it fast?

Breaking it down in a different way, assume this is my data:

```
id price quantity
1   10    2
1   20    1
1   50    5
2   5     5
2   3     6 
2   10    4
```

So here the solution for ID = 1 would be: `( 10 * 2 + 20*1 +50 * 5 ) / (2+1+5) = 36.25` This gives me the price pr. unit for all units with the ID = 1.

Updated, using `set.seed(1234)` and this datageneration:

```
set.seed(1234)
df<- data.frame( id <-sample(1:10,100, replace = T),
price <-runif(20)*100,
q = sample(1:100,100, replace = T))
colnames(df)<-c("id","price","quantity")
```

The results should look like this :

```
id avg.price.per.unit
1 33,71
2 29,84
3 44,53
4 36,27
5 69,63
6 35,99
7 45,26
8 58,32
9 33,36
10 9,67
```

The rounding might be a little off.

Comment: I've added the "Breaking down", since the previous solution from Manetheran is taking a very long time to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `ddply` from the `plyr` library. [EDIT] Now that the poster has (finally) defined for us the precise calculation he/she wants, the solution is straightforward.

```
set.seed(1234)
df<- data.frame( id <-sample(1:10,100, replace = T),
price <-runif(20)*100,
q = sample(1:100,100, replace = T))
colnames(df)<-c("id","price","quantity")

library(plyr)

df2 <- ddply(df, .(id), summarise,
             price.x.quantity = sum(price*quantity),
             sum.q = sum(quantity))
df2$avg <- with(df2, price.x.quantity/sum.q)
df2
```

Which gives this:

```
> df2
   id price.x.quantity sum.q       avg
1   1        17668.111   524 33.717769
2   2        18559.773   622 29.838863
3   3        35222.731   791 44.529369
4   4        28433.181   784 36.266813
5   5        10304.568   148 69.625462
6   6        31534.830   876 35.998665
7   7        29513.494   652 45.266095
8   8        25542.908   438 58.317141
9   9        22216.174   666 33.357619
10 10         2263.581   234  9.673423
>
```

Comment: This gives me the average price (only across price). Im looking for the average price pr. quantity. It's fitting the function in at      
df2 <- ddply(df, .(id), summarise, avg.price = HERE) im having trouble with?

Answer (score 2):

You could apply the function across all your unique ids:

```
avgPrices <- sapply(unique(df$id), function(i) {
  sum(((df$p[df$id == i ])*(df$q[df$id == i ])/(sum(df$q[df$id == i ]))))
})
result <- cbind(unique(df$id), avgPrices)
colnames(result) <- c("id", "avg.price")
```

Or more simply using the `plyr` package:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df, .(id), summarize, avg.price=sum(price/quantity))
```

Or alternatively you could take an `SQL` approach:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("SELECT id, sum(price/quantity) AS 'avg.price' FROM df GROUP BY id")
```

Comment: Im having trouble getting your first solution working, which I think is what im looking for. I want sum(p_ij*q_ij + p_ik * q_ik + ...) / sum (q_ij + qik + ...) for each ID. As far as I can see the plyr does not do this.

Comment: Are you able to do it with the first method (`sapply`), or adjust the calculation there? I'm a little confused as to what your `j` and `k` would be in this situation.

Comment: Sweet, got your first example to work, just missing a paranthesis after }

Comment: Can this be speeded up some how? right now is still calculating at its been around 15 minuts.

Comment: Look at the `ddply`code above (which is basically the same as the `ddply` code @Manetheran provided in his answer). You will see that if you increase the rows in `df` from 100 to 200,000 the whole operation still only takes a second or two.

Comment: The 3 code examples does not do the same thing! The first makes an average price per unit of quantity, which is not what the other two examples do.

Comment: Actually if you look at my answer you will see that the results of the `ddply` calculation exactly match your results in the example in your question, but that's not the point. The point is that the ddply solution (mine or Manetheran's) will do the whole example with 200k rows in a second or so. Whether it's average price, price per unit of quantity or whatever doesn't make an appreciable difference for a problem of this size.

Comment: @ SlowLearner: Sorry, but I cannot get library(plyr)
ddply(df, .(id)... or the library(sqldf)... to give the correct results. These two give other results than the avgPrices <- sapply... I've just run them all three again. Thanks for the help, your new suggestion does work.